# Don't think I have enough adapters to set up static networking?

Tags: virtualbox, network-interface

Currently I have bridged networking set up on VirtualBox.
In my CentOS machine, when I type `ifconfig -a` I only have an eth0 and lo interface. Similarly in Windows Server 2008, there is only one Local Area Connection. My understanding is that an interface corresponds to an adapter, and the eth0/Local Area Connection is used for connection to the 'outside world.'
I am trying to set up static networking between the two environments, and therefore need another interface (eth1 and Local Area Connection 2). However I cannot seem to create these interfaces. Does this mean interfaces are automatically generated when an adapter is detected?

What can I do?

Comment: How many Network Cards are there in Your Physical Machine?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion all, I am running native Windows. On top of that I have a CentOS and Windows Server 2008 VM running in VirtualBox. I am trying to set up connectivity between the CentOS and Windows Server 2008. At first I changed the eth0/Local Area Connection ip addresses to put them on the same 10.0.2.0/24 subnet, however this did not look right as I thought that I should have a separate eth1/LAC2 for a LAN.

Comment: Also even after putting them onto the same subnet it didn't work. I know I do not require a default gateway because they're in the same subnet but even so I put in .1 as a default gateway, and strangely from the Windows Server I  could not ping the default gateway.

Comment: @eyoung100 I have one Network Card I think.

Comment: Another detail - currently I can connect to the Internet because Bridged networking is set up on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out as trivial as it sounds. Went to Machine -> Settings -> Network -> Adapter under VirtualBox.
Managed to add virtual adapters and hence more interfaces were generated.

Answer (score 3):

"Bridged networking" will set up a bridge and connect the single interface of each VM to that bridge. VirtualBox will all so add your hosts network connection to that bridge.

Therefore VMs can talk to each other and also access to the outside like the internet.

This especially means that both VMs are it the same LAN and can directly connect to each other.

Please add more details to your question if I misunderstood your question. (Especially your meaning of "static networking" is unclear to me.)

Answer (score 0):

> $> dmesg | grep eth

This will show you the instances of Ethernet adapters detected by your Linux Kernel. I believe that you are requiring a TUN/TAP virtual interfaces if the virtual machines are hosted on your Linux system.

Within the output of the command at the top of my Answer, you will see all your Ethernet interfaces detected. Please tell me if you see an "eth0" and an "eth1." If your eth1 is detected in DMESG, but not in the output of ifconfig, there is a troubleshooting SOP we can follow to solve this for you.

**Interfaces are automatically generated when an adapter is created, and if it's not immediate, it will be detected on the next start-up of your machine**

**Static interfaces are generally editable within */etc/rc.d/rc.inet***, a startup script which runs on the start-up of your machine, and persists your network configuration between run-levels.

Comment: [root@localhost project1]# dmesg | grep eth
e1000: eth0: e1000_probe: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
e1000: eth0: e1000_watchdog_task: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth0
e1000: eth0: e1000_watchdog_task: NIC Link is Down
e1000: eth0: e1000_watchdog_task: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None

Comment: It seems that there is no eth1 unfortunately shown by dmesg